# Opengl - rotation, scale, translation

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft, minecraft-forge

**Question:** What is the order to apply rotation, scale, and translation for rendering using opengl?

**Currently** I'm running the code as

- GL11.glScaled(scale value)
- GL11.glRotated(x) //pitch
- GL11.glRotated(y) //yaw
- GL11.glRotated(z) //roll
- GL11.glTranslated(x, y, z)

**I've tried** changing the order with a lot of different results. Some configuration improve the rendering, for example, scaling last doesn't mess with the translation. However, it seems to break the rotation causing pitch and roll to both roll the model.

**Some extra information:**
The code is for a Minecraft mod that renders items using JSON data. The exact code can be found here:
https://github.com/VoltzEngine-Project/Engine/blob/development/src/main/scala/com/builtbroken/mc/client/json/render/state/ModelState.java#L48

Code added to post by request of BDL

```
package com.builtbroken.mc.client.json.render.state;

import com.builtbroken.jlib.helpers.MathHelper;
import com.builtbroken.mc.client.SharedAssets;
import com.builtbroken.mc.client.json.ClientDataHandler;
import com.builtbroken.mc.client.json.imp.IModelState;
import com.builtbroken.mc.client.json.models.ModelData;
import com.builtbroken.mc.client.json.texture.TextureData;
import com.builtbroken.mc.imp.transform.rotation.EulerAngle;
import com.builtbroken.mc.imp.transform.vector.Pos;
import cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

/**
 * Render/Texture/Animation states used for rendering models in the game
 *
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/BuiltBrokenModding/VoltzEngine/blob/development/license.md">License</a> for what you can and can't do with the code.
 * Created by Dark(DarkGuardsman, Robert) on 11/22/2016.
 */
public class ModelState extends TextureState implements IModelState
{
    public String modelID;
    public String[] parts;
    public Pos offset;
    public Pos scale;
    public EulerAngle rotation;

    public boolean renderParent = false;
    public boolean renderOnlyParts = true;

    public ModelState(String ID)
    {
        super(ID);
    }

    public ModelState(String ID, String modelID, Pos offset, Pos scale, EulerAngle rotation)
    {
        this(ID);
        this.modelID = modelID;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean render(boolean subRender, float yaw, float pitch, float roll)
    {
        TextureData textureData = getTexture(); //Texture reference, texture is .png loaded using property code owned by Mojang so can not be shared
        ModelData data = getModel(); //Model reference, model is .obj rendered using triangles
        if (data != null && data.getModel() != null)
        {
            //Starts rendering by storing previous matrix
            GL11.glPushMatrix();

            if (!subRender)
            {
                //TODO handle parent additions, in which parent and child data are combined
                //Scales object by value
                if (scale != null)
                {
                    GL11.glScaled(scale.x(), scale.y(), scale.z());
                }
                else if (parentState instanceof IModelState && ((IModelState) parentState).getScale() != null)
                {
                    GL11.glScaled(((IModelState) parentState).getScale().x(), ((IModelState) parentState).getScale().y(), ((IModelState) parentState).getScale().z());
                }

                //Rotates object, needs to be handled after scaling
                if (rotation != null)
                {
                    GL11.glRotated(MathHelper.clampAngleTo360(rotation.pitch() + pitch), 1, 0, 0);
                    GL11.glRotated(MathHelper.clampAngleTo360(rotation.yaw() + yaw), 0, 1, 0);
                    GL11.glRotated(MathHelper.clampAngleTo360(rotation.roll() + roll), 0, 0, 1);
                }
                else if (parentState instanceof IModelState && ((IModelState) parentState).getRotation() != null)
                {
                    GL11.glRotated(MathHelper.clampAngleTo360(((IModelState) parentState).getRotation().pitch() + pitch), 1, 0, 0);
                    GL11.glRotated(MathHelper.clampAngleTo360(((IModelState) parentState).getRotation().yaw() + yaw), 0, 1, 0);
                    GL11.glRotated(MathHelper.clampAngleTo360(((IModelState) parentState).getRotation().roll() + roll), 0, 0, 1);
                }

                //Moves the object
                if (offset != null)
                {
                    GL11.glTranslated(offset.x(), offset.y(), offset.z());
                }
                else if (parentState instanceof IModelState && ((IModelState) parentState).getOffset() != null)
                {
                    GL11.glTranslated(((IModelState) parentState).getOffset().x(), ((IModelState) parentState).getOffset().y(), ((IModelState) parentState).getOffset().z());
                }
            }

            //Render parent
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            if (parentState instanceof IModelState)
            {
                if (renderParent)
                {
                    ((IModelState) parentState).render(true);
                }
                else if (parts == null && parentState instanceof ModelState && ((ModelState) parentState).renderParent)
                {
                    if (((ModelState) parentState).parentState instanceof IModelState)
                    {
                        ((IModelState) ((ModelState) parentState).parentState).render(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            GL11.glPopMatrix();

            //Binds texture
            if (textureData != null)
            {
                FMLClientHandler.instance().getClient().renderEngine.bindTexture(textureData.getLocation());
            }
            else
            {
                //Backup texture bind, if no texture
                FMLClientHandler.instance().getClient().renderEngine.bindTexture(SharedAssets.GREY_TEXTURE);
            }

            //Render model
            data.render(renderOnlyParts, getPartsToRender());

            //Ends render by restoring previous matrix(rotation, position, etc)
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Pos getScale()
    {
        if (scale == null)
        {
            return parentState instanceof IModelState ? ((IModelState) parentState).getScale() : null;
        }
        else if (parentState instanceof IModelState)
        {
            //TODO add to parent rotation, or null out rotation
            //TODO setup logic via configs to allow users to decide how rotation is used
        }
        return scale;
    }

    @Override
    public Pos getOffset()
    {
        if (offset == null)
        {
            return parentState instanceof IModelState ? ((IModelState) parentState).getOffset() : null;
        }
        else if (parentState instanceof IModelState)
        {
            //TODO add to parent rotation, or null out rotation
            //TODO setup logic via configs to allow users to decide how rotation is used
        }
        return offset;
    }

    @Override
    public EulerAngle getRotation()
    {
        if (rotation == null)
        {
            return parentState instanceof IModelState ? ((IModelState) parentState).getRotation() : null;
        }
        else if (parentState instanceof IModelState)
        {
            //TODO add to parent rotation, or null out rotation
            //TODO setup logic via configs to allow users to decide how rotation is used
        }
        return rotation;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelData getModel()
    {
        if (parentState instanceof IModelState)
        {
            return ((IModelState) parentState).getModel();
        }
        return ClientDataHandler.INSTANCE.getModel(modelID);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPartsToRender()
    {
        if (parentState instanceof IModelState && (parts == null || parts.length == 0))
        {
            return ((IModelState) parentState).getPartsToRender();
        }
        return parts;
    }

    @Override
    public TextureData getTexture()
    {
        TextureData textureData = ClientDataHandler.INSTANCE.getTexture(textureID);
        if (textureData == null && parentState instanceof IModelState)
        {
            return ((IModelState) parentState).getTexture();
        }
        return textureData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include all the code necessary to reproduce your problem **in the question itself**

Comment: Does a link to the source not count? As the post would be rather long if I add in all of the code. Not including the code it is dependent on such as the game Minecraft, its libraries, and several of my own.

Comment: No, linking to the code is not sufficient. Since this question and answers are not just for you but also for future visitors, it is important to have everything relevant contained in the question. If the link dies, the question would get useless. You might want to read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I understand that, but the linked code in this question would be optional. As I'm asking a basic question and have included my order of rendering called for opengl 11 at the top. Anything beyond this would just extend the post length wasting time.  However, if you insist I will edit the post.

Comment: @derhass I'm looking for an explanation of the order and why its important. Most of what I've been finding are examples of how to do rendering with matrixes. Most of the explanation is lost in trying to understand how the matrix works in relations to the simple opengl calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this order of operations for the usual use case: Scale -> Rotate -> Translate

For the rotation itself, an intuitive convention is first roll, then pitch and at the end yaw. Rolling happens along an axis of the object. Pitch up or down the rolled object. Then horizontally orient the model.

Scaling happens in object model coordinates.
Rotation after the scale happens so you're rotating the scaled model with respect to the scene frame. Eventually you use translation last to place the resulting transformed object into place.

You sometimes need to do a previous round of scale and rotation to account for the tool/engine differences in right-handedness, coordinates (Z is up or Y is up.) and scale

Comment: That seems to be the order I'm using unless I'm misunderstanding something. Anyways I'll try the rotation change to see if that helps.

Comment: Changing the order of rotation has at least fixed a few of my model errors. Going to do more testing but thank you for that :)

Comment: Note that the order of rotation is important! [Doing them in another order gives different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0lJy.gif). This is why quaternions are used, which can be computed as a single Matrix4x4 and applied all at once.